# how to change Background of the last item only in Recylerview

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the background in the last item, but I encountered a strange problem !
When making a condition, I put the last position
I find that the result changes the background in the last element and another element!

All I want is to change the background in the last element only

This my code

```
        if(position==(getItemCount()-1)) {

        holder.coin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.coin0);

       }
```

Comment: explain, please. Are you making a music player type recycler view

Comment: you need to write else part too . In else part set the default background .

Comment: give us your layout for the recycleview item

Comment: You have formulated the question in a better way
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376080/how-to-make-animation-of-the-last-item-only-in-recylerview

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is like,

1. You set background for the last element
2. Then you click another and change background for the last element

But then the last to last element's background is also there. If that's the problem then here is the solution.

Before setting background do this in ViewHodler Class in the recycler view class:
In the onClick, do

```
notifyItemChanged(positionOfLastToLastElement);
```

then set the background in this way you will have only one item with that background.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376080/how-to-make-animation-of-the-last-item-only-in-recylerview